# Withdrawing flags

Tags: support, flagging

Is there any way to withdraw flags?

[This answer](https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/23475/9550) was auto-flagged as low quality because of its length. When I viewed the flag, the system only showed the textual part of the answer and not the accompanying diagram. Because of that, I flagged as "not an answer". Having now seen the diagram, it seems that it is, in fact, a perfectly valid attempt at an answer<sup>1</sup> and I wouldn't have flagged it if I'd seen the whole thing.<sup>2</sup>  I tried to raise a "Needs moderator attention" flag with an explanation of why my previous flag should be ignored but the system let me type my 500 characters and then told me I'd already flagged that post so couldn't flag it again!

---

<sup>1</sup> I say "attempt" just because I've not tried to verify the correctness of the answer.
<sup>2</sup> If other people think the answer should have been flagged, diagram notwithstanding, that's a separate discussion, please.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think you can withdraw flags.

If you accidentally vote or flag, you can

- hope other users resp. mods overrule you or
- ping mods in chat.

Remember that a single user flag does not effect anything; other humans will look at it. So, usually, no harm will be done.

Comment: I was partly worrying that the other humans who looked at it might also only see the textual part of the answer and get the same misleading view that I did.

Comment: @DavidRicherby: I understand. For what it's worth, I think an answer that contains not much but a picture is bad, anyway. Nevertheless, it's a bug; you should search for it on [meta.SE] and open a new question if it's not a known problem.